# LINQ to SQL - Querying exact values

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows, linq

I have a query that will retrieve number > 15, although when I try and specify an exact value, for example "== "2"" I get errors

```
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(); 
    var returnunits15 = from p in db.Products 
            where p.UnitPrice > 15 // If unit price is greater than 15...
            select p; // select entries
```

E.g. how could I adapt the query to look for an exact string e.g. "test"

and

and exact value for example 20.?

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnitPrice` is decimal?
You can't compare numeric types with strings.

If you want to check for equality for numeric types, you don't need to use "" quote marks.

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(); 
var returnunits15 = from p in db.Products 
        where p.UnitPrice == 20
        select p;
```

You need to use quote marks for string comparison only.

Comment: Surely you meant `p.UnitPrice == 20`, no? ;)

Comment: @Alex Aza sorry that was a bad example. but in the case it was e.g. UnitName, how could you search for a string?

Comment: @James - for string comparison you do `p.UnitName == "test"`.

Comment: @James: You'd put `p.UnitName == "whateverName"`

Comment: @Alex Aza I tried this before and still getting the same error when doing it: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal?' and 'string'"

Comment: @James - this is because your field is decimal. Check the type of your field.